# Could someone please help translate this For loop short cut to its normal state

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, while-loop, shortcut

could someone assist me on both translating this example to a full written for loop and also to a while loop as I am trying to understand this short cut but i am unsure of exactly what it means??

```
double a = 0;
for(int b : c)
    a += b;
a /= c.length;
return a
```

Comment: Search for for-each loop.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an equivalent "normal" (non-enhanced) `for` loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
    int b = c[i];
    a += b;
}
```

And the corresponding `while` loop:

```
int i = 0;
while (i < c.length) {
    int b = c[i];
    a += b;
    i++
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for loop:

```
double a = 0;
for (int b : c) {
    a = a + b;
}
a = a / c.length;
return a;
```

while loop:

```
double a = 0;
int i = 0;
while (i < c.length) {
    a = a + c[i];
    i++;
}
a = a / c.length;
return a;
```

c appears to be an `int[]`

Answer (score 0):

This loop is actually calculating the average of a series of numbers. Observe with `a` renamed to `average`, `b` renamed to `currentValue`, and `c` renamed to `values`:

```
double average = 0;
for(int currentValue : values)
    average += currentValue;
average /= values.length;
return average;
```

There is no "short-cut" per-se, just some syntax shortcuts. Here's how the full version might look:

```
double average = 0;
for (int currentValue : values) {
  average = average + currentValue;
}
average = average / values.length;
return average;
```

As a while loop:

```
double average = 0;
int index = 0;
while (index < values.length) {
  int currentValue = values[i];
  average = average + currentValue;
}
average = average / values.length;
return average;
```